# Young man sent to Earth by aliens to help humans become adaptable

Tags: story-identification

I remember a science fiction story I read back in the 70s which means it was probably written in the 60s.  The plot of the story is a young man is returned to earth by an alien race.  Earth has become so dependent upon technology and medicine to maintain itself that they can no longer adapt to changes in their environment.  The returned human is there to reverse the problem.  Any idea as to what the name of this book/short story might be or who may have written it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Please check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking story-id questions to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 1):

This might be  "Prodigal Sun" by Philip E.High. Radiation from the sun is causing the adaption problems, and the man releases a gas into the atmosphere to form a shield.https://www.fantasticfiction.com/h/philip-e-high/prodigal-sun.htm

Comment: That’s it.  Thank you.  I was sure Prodigal Son was part of the title....